# Android Mapview Markers Adding & Updating ?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-mapview

I'm new to android development. would like to add and update markers on the mapview.

My Custom Class --> '**Vehicle**' property is **Id,Plate,Lat,Long,Icon_Url** 
I fill it(**List<>**) with json(timer async task running 1-2 mins).

Add to map these values ​​and want to update with new data location.(Lat,Long property)

e.g

Vehicle First Values :
Id : 10005
Plate : XXXX
Lat : 99.99999
Long : 99.9999
Icon_Url : http://example.com/img/1.png

Create marker with this values and Add marker on Mapview.

Running timer, Later Vehicle Second Values :

Id : 10005
Plate : XXXX
Lat : 11.1111
Long : 11.1111
Icon_Url : http://example.com/img/2.png

Update marker lat,long and icon url.

How can I do it?

Thank u.

Comment: The documentation for the Map API is pretty good.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: thank u Ben but I do not think that is enough.